# Classes and arrow functions and THIS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, es6-class, arrow-functions

While learning JS and React I've come across confusing differences in tutorials.

I'll split the questions below with examples. I understand bind for regular functions and this context, it's just arrow functions and how I've seen them used/declared that's confusing.

Please don't just refer to duplicates as I've found conflicting answers in tutorials which have confused me, so looking for the source of truth to understand in a simple way. Answers related to the questions and examples below would help better.

1 - I've seen examples where a tutorial says the value of 'this' would be window as the arrow function inherits from the global/window scope but I've also seen tutorials where they say it will inherit this from the class context - which is correct? if you could please explain.

```js
class MyClass {
    value = 'Hello World!'
    clickHandler = () => { console.log(this.value) };
}
```

2 - I have 2 parts to this question -
i - Why is the syntax clickHandler = () => rather than clickHandler () =>

I ask this because I read class methods can be defined with 'functionName () {}' so why do arrow functions treat the method name as a variable?

ii - What is the value of this in the below code? same as question 1 I guess, does this refer to the window object or the class?

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
  }
  clickhandler = () => {
    console.log("you clicked me!!")
  }
  render() {
    return( 
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.clickhandler}> // => CALLBACK
```

3 - Here I see the event handler is an inline function, but it looks like it gets invoked because of the () at the end, sometimes as in the follow on snippet, you can see that just the function name is given without the parentheses, shouldn't they be there also?

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  showValue() {
    console.log(this.props.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.showValue()}>Do Something</button>
    );
  }
}

-------------------------------------------

showValue() {
    console.log(this.props.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.showValue}>Do Something</button>
    );
  }
```

Comment: very long but good question

Comment: Thanks but once you read it through - its just 3 examples on similar themes so hopefully not too long.

Comment: Please ask a single question per post only.

Comment: @Bergi sure, these just seemed closely related so I kept them in one post this time.

Comment: @jobe 3 isn't directly related to 1 and 2 and deserved to be a separate question.

Comment: @estus fair point, noted for next time.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is the syntax clickHandler = () => rather than clickHandler () =>

`foo () => ...` syntax isn't valid for ES6 classes and this concept wouldn't make sense. `foo() {...}` is syntactic sugar for prototype method:

```
function Class() {}
Class.prototype.foo = function () {
  // this instanceof Class === true
}
```

This wouldn't work if `Class.prototype.foo` were an arrow; `this` would be retrieved from the scope where `Class` is defined:

```
// this === undefined

Class.prototype.foo = () => {
  // this === undefined
}
```

`foo = () => ...` is [class field](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) syntax, which is stage 3 proposal and not a part of ES6.

```
class Class {
  foo = () => {
    // this instanceof Class === true 
  }
}
```

is syntactic sugar for:

```
class Class {
  constructor() {
    // this instanceof Class === true 
    this.foo = () => {
      // this instanceof Class === true 
    }
  }
}
```

> I've seen examples where a tutorial says the value of this would be window as the arrow function inherits from the global/window scope but I've also seen tutorials where they say it will inherit this from the class context/scope - which is correct?

Arrow function gets lexical `this` from enclosing scope. In case an arrow is defined in global scope, `this` is `window`, and `undefined` in ES module scope.

In the example above an arrow is defined in class constructor scope, `this` is class instance.

> Here I see the event handler is an inline function, but it looks like it gets invoked because of the () at the end, sometimes as in the follow on snippet, you can see that just the function name is given without the parentheses, shouldn't they be there also?

Callback function is expected to be passed as `onClick` prop. `this.showValue()` calls a function and returns a value from it. Unless a value is a function, too, invoking a method in-place like `onClick={this.showValue()}` is incorrect.

`onClick={this.showValue}` passes class method as a callback. Since `showValue` is prototype method that isn't bound to proper `this` context, a callback will be executed with wrong context (the problem is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)), while `onClick={() => this.showValue()}` passes wrapper function as a callback that executes `showValue` with correct context.

Comment: I actually have a similar question on number 3 and wondering how should we pass along parameter `onClick={this.showValue}`?

Comment: Which parameter? The example in the question doesn't contain parameters. In case there should be something else besides `event` object from click event, it should be wrapped with a function any way, `onClick={e => this.showValue('foo')}`

Comment: @estus My first question with the specific example I gave still confuses me, what is the enclosing scope here? is it the class or is it the window? As I said, I've seen both answers given in tutorials.

Comment: @estus I'm afraid without reference to the questions and numbers I gave them, I didn't follow the rest of your explanation and got a bit lost.

Comment: I updated the answer to be more specific. The code contains comments about what `this` is in this specific case. As for `foo = () =>...` class method, `this` is class instance and the answer explains why.

Comment: @estus I will take a look again, would be easier if the order matched the questions.

Comment: I've tried to give the information in the order that makes sense. 1 and 2 questions aren't independent.

Comment: @estus Just going through your answer properly now - to confirm I understand correctly - there isn't a way to define a class method like this? "foo () =>" if so then I understand.

The class field syntax is ok because this already refers to the class because the arrow function was actually defined in the constructor behind the scenes, is that correct?

I think I understand 1 and 2 so far then.

With 3 I don't fully understand, could you clarify a bit more simply please.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. As for 3, I'll try to sum this up. `onClick` expects a function. `this.showValue() === undefined`, so `onClick={this.showValue()}` is just wrong but `onClick={this.showValue}` is correct. It won't work because `showValue` isn't bound. Try to do `let onClick = this.showValue; onClick()` yourself and see what happens, it will choke on `this.props` because it was called with wrong context. `onClick={() => this.showValue()}` will work because it's called with right context.

Comment: `onClick={this.showValue}` may work too, if `showValue` is an arrow method OR it's proto method that was bound like `showValue = this.showValue.bind(this); showValue() {...}`.

Comment: @estus I think I understand a bit clearer but still not fully, why does this.showValue passed without parentheses work as a callback but with parentheses it doesn't? Surely you need the parentheses to invoke the function when a click happens.

Comment: Because `this.showValue` is a function, and `this.showValue()` is a value that is returned from this function, which is `undefined`. You don't need to pass `undefined` to `onClick`. You can log both to the console to check. *Surely you need the parentheses to invoke the function when a click happens.* - you don't need to call it, React will do for you. A callback is a function that will be *called back* later. A place where you pass a callback is responsible for calling it.

Answer (score 1):

**1-** `this` refers to current scope. In `MyClass` this refers to class instance. 
So the answer is both correct. In global scope this refers to the window, inside `myclass` this refers to the class.

**2-** As you may notice in arrow function there's no need to bind functions with the class, so there syntax is different.

**3-** `onClick={() => this.showValue()}>Do Something</button>` : creates a function each time click fires an event. It is useful when in some cases you want to pass extra args from component render to event handler.

`onClick={() => this.showValue(event, id, name)}>Do Something</button>`

but with `onClick={this.showValue}>Do Something</button>` which is the usual case, you call the handler when it fires an event without creating new function each time.

**But how it can identifies the handler?** By binding, `this` can recognize what is inside your scope because you are calling it inside which is `showValue`

Comment: No, the `this` keyword never refers to a "*scope*".

Comment: @Bergi Can you shed some light please? for question 1 I've seen answers for both class context and window.

Comment: @jobe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this. Estus' answer is correct, in an arrow function that is created in the constructor of a class, `this` refers to the instance.

Comment: @Bergi Ah ok that makes sense but I wonder in what scenario I saw in some tutorials where they said the arrow function's lexical value of 'this' would be window, this is what I found confusing.

Comment: @jobe The value of the `this` value depends on where the arrow function is defined and (if in a function) how that function is called. If the tutorial was talking about an arrow function in the context of a `class` constructor, it was just plain wrong.

Comment: @Bergi i said that it refers to instance and pointed out when it is global and when it is not my intention was to simplify things

Comment: @Jalal Still "*refers to current scope*" is wrong (at least the terminology)

Comment: @Bergi but outside of a constructor is there any way an arrow function can be defined in a class then? I can't think of any either. There is the new class property syntax I've just read about today but that is pulled into the constructor also behind the scenes.

Comment: @jobe The arrow function can also be defined in a normal class method, and then its `this` depends on how the method is called. Usually on an instance, but you never know.

Comment: @Bergi can you give a simple example please, I can't think of one. In my first question I had this 'clickHandler = () => { }' - but that will not be a normal class method would it?

Comment: @jobe `method() { const arr = () => { console.log(this; }; arr(); }`